# solving a optimisation problem with max of a variable

Tags: matlab

Original Question - Find the optimal mixed - strategy for player one given the payoff matrix

```
0 2 1 -1
3 4 0 -5 
-1 3 0 2 
-1 -1 2 1
```

I have the following maximisation problem
max v

s.t
3p1 -p3 -2p4 <= v

2p1 +4p2 +3p3 -p4 <= v

p1 +2p4 <= v

-p1 -5p2 +2p3+p4n <= v

where pi <0

I have used the following code for a maximisation problem previously but I am unsure how to adapt it for this problem due to the max function being v

```
% max 6x - y s.t.
% 4y - x >= 10
% 2x + y <= 10
% 2y - x <=  5

f = -[6;-1];          % objective function
A = [1 -4; 2 1; -1 2];    % constraint matrix
b = [-10 10 5];           % constraing rhs
Aeq = [];               % no equality constraints here
beq = [];               % no equality constraints here
lb = [];    
ub = [];

%% call linprog
optimum = linprog(f,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, how can you maximise `v` and use it as a constraint at the same time? You could have `v=1e5` and satisfy a range of values for `p_i`, but then you have `v=1e6` which is larger and all of the previous constraints would surely be satisfied just fine... you could keep increasing `v`? Do you want to _minimise_ `v`?

Comment: its trying to find the optimal mixed strategy for player 1 in a zero sum game

Comment: Something seems wrong with the problem formulation, for the reasoning in my first comment

Comment: I am being asked to find an optimal mixed strategy for player 1 given A = payoff matrix

Comment: I think you need to [edit] the question to include the original problem statement, otherwise this is at risk of becoming an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/358485)

Comment: edited the post to include the question I am trying to solve

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, if you are talking about the matrix this is what it said to write and I'm not sure how to format it in another way

Comment: the question I am trying to solve is in the edited version of the question, I need to find the optimal mixed strategy for the pay off matrix above

Comment: The method in the accepted answer here looks like it might be applicable to your problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3477714/283393. Note that this solution maximises `1/V`, not V. You may be able to solve it using hand-calcs with this approach, or it may at least help you better formulate the MATLAB solution